# axios post request with formData using AxiosInstance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I need to send a binary file through axios post request-

```
let data= await axios.post(url, formDataObj,config)
```

here formDataObj is object of [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)
and config is an object that contains headers for API

This is working fine for me
But I want to use [axiosInstance.request()](https://axios-http.com/docs/instance) for this instead of axios.post()

```
const response = await axiosInstance.request(reqObj);
```

how can i pass formData in it? what is the syntax for that?

Comment: From what I can see in the [documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config), you could prepare your `formDataObj` beforehand, and then, within the request do something like `axiosInstance.request({ url: url, type: 'POST',data:formDataObj,headers: {'content-type':'multipart/form-data'}})`. What happens when you try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example code maybe helpful

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('someFile', myFile, 'test.jpg'); 
formData.append('anotherField', 'value');

const reqConfig = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'your-api-url',
  data: formData,
  headers: {
    // Add headers here
  }
};

const response = await axiosInstance.request(reqConfig);
```

Comment: Be careful! No need to specify Content-Type in header: Axios automatically sets it to multipart/form-data when using FormData